# how to achieve a one-to-many relation using jpa

Tags: jpa, one-to-many, jpql

i am just wondering if you guys could shed some light on something that is confusing me

i have two tables one `userdetails`

```
create table usertable (
        username varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        password varchar(128) NOT NULL
);
```

and one `addresses`, how can i map it in JPA that i could have one user to many addresses, how can this be achieved, does it have to be done at the table creation or done in the classes ?

thanks

EDITTTT

```
create table usertable (
        username varchar(128) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT USER_PK PRIMARY KEY ,
        password varchar(128) NOT NULL,
firstaname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
surname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
gender varchar(6) NOT NULL,
homenumber varchar(128) NOT NULL,
mobilenumber varchar(128) NOT NULL,
dob date NOT NULL,
id INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1)
);


create table grouptable(
        username varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        groupid  varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT GROUP_PK PRIMARY KEY(username, groupid),
        CONSTRAINT USER_FK FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES usertable(username)
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT
    );

create table address(
username varchar(128) NOT NULL,
                addressline1 varchar(128) NOT NULL,
                addressline2 varchar(128) NOT NULL,
                addressline3 varchar(128) NOT NULL,
                country varchar(128) NOT NULL,
                postcode varchar(9) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT USER2_FK FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES usertable(username)
                     );
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be specified in your Entity classes. Here is a quick example using annotations.

```
@Entity
public class UserDetail {
  @Id
  @Column(name="ID")
  private long id;
  ...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="userdetail")
  private List<Address> addresses;
  ...
}

@Entity
public class Address {
  @Id
  private long id;
  ...
  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="userdetail")
  private UserDetail userdetail;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks that makes sense, in the actual db set up does it need to be set up with foreign keys etc ? or just two tables and this is how they are linked ?

Comment: It makes sense to set it up with foreign keys, the address will have a column named userdetail which is a foreign key to the userdetail table's id column.

Comment: I have added the code i currently use for data table generation above, how would i add a foreign key here ?